# Deleting dynamically allocated array vs single pointer

Tags: c++, delete-operator

So I'm trying to implement a unique pointer and I want to be able to choose between allocating a single object and allocating an array.

Let's say if I allocated everything with `new[]` even the single object(`new[1]`) instead of choosing between `new T(Args...)` and `new[n] T(Args...)` depending on the constructor params,
would deleting like this:

```cpp
delete[] this->ptr;
```

have any drawbacks vs

```cpp
if (1 < size) {
    delete[] this->ptr; // this was allocated with new[]
    return;
}
delete this->ptr; // this was allocated with new
```

Thanks for the answer(s) in advance.

Comment: The only drawback is that (maybe, maybe not) a few extra bytes of RAM will be needed. RAM is cheap these days.

Comment: If you're going to reinvent the wheel, you should take a look at the [wheel](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr), to see (at the very least) the interface it uses.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I have read both MSVC(only headers) and GCC implementations of the pointers, so don't assume I came here unprepared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, a unique pointer works by taking ownership of a bare pointer provided by the client: `unique_ptr::unique_ptr(T*)`. In such case, it would be somewhat limiting for the client that they are not allowed to pass pointers to array of size 1 (in one choice of implementation), or that they are not supposed to pass pointers to non-arrays (the other choice).

Furthermore, both choices introduce extra, although tiny overhead. One choice has a branch, and the other stores the size of the array, which isn't necessary for non-array allocation.

The way the standard unique pointer is specified, the client gets to choose which limitation they want to have. To use the non-array delete, you instantiate `unique_ptr<T>`, and to use array delete, you instantiate `unique_ptr<T[]>` specialisation. And because the choice is at compile time, there is no need for a runtime branch.